# How check that method was called with correct param in unit test SinonJs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

How I can check that methods **this.athena.startQueryExecution(param)** was called with correct param in unit test using sinon? And is it possible?

I have a simple code, which runs query to database:

```
    export class QueryService {

    private readonly athena: Athena = new Athena();

    constructor() {
    }

    public async query(date?: Date) {

         const param = {
            QueryString: this.generateQuery(date),
        };

        await this.athena.startQueryExecution(param)
            .promise();
   }

    private generateQuery(date?: Date): string {

        if (date) {
            return `SELECT * FROM TABLE
                    WHERE date='$date'
        } else {
            return `SELECT * FROM TABLE
                    WHERE date='any date'
        }
    }
```

My test:

```
describe('QueryService', () => {

    let queryService = new QueryService();

    describe('Query', () => {

        it('test', async () => {

            // given
            const date: Date = {date: "2019-01-01"};

            // where
            queryService.query(date);

            // then

        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unit test solution:

`queryService.ts`:

```js
import { Athena } from './athena';

export class QueryService {
  private readonly athena: Athena = new Athena();
  constructor() {}
  public async query(date?: Date) {
    const param = {
      QueryString: this.generateQuery(date),
    };

    return this.athena.startQueryExecution(param).promise();
  }

  private generateQuery(date?: Date): string {
    if (date) {
      return `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date='$date'`;
    } else {
      return `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date='any date'`;
    }
  }
}
```

`athena.ts`:

```js
export class Athena {
  public startQueryExecution(param) {
    return this;
  }
  public async promise() {
    return 'real data';
  }
}
```

`queryService.test.ts`:

```js
import { QueryService } from './queryService';
import { Athena } from './athena';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('60997196', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const startQueryExecutionStub = sinon.stub(Athena.prototype, 'startQueryExecution').returnsThis();
    const promiseStub = sinon.stub(Athena.prototype, 'promise').resolves('fake data');
    const queryService = new QueryService();
    const date: Date = new Date('2019-01-01');
    const actual = await queryService.query(date);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'fake data');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(startQueryExecutionStub, {
      QueryString: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date='$date'`,
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(promiseStub);
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
  60997196
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (29ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |   72.73 |       50 |      60 |   72.73 |                   
 athena.ts       |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |   33.33 | 3,6               
 queryService.ts |    87.5 |       50 |     100 |    87.5 | 18                
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/expressjs-research/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60997196